# Get a web page icon in PyQt4.QtWebKit

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I want to make a simple web browser.When I navigate between web pages I want to get the icon of the current web page.

```
self.setWindowIcon(QWebSettings.iconForUrl(QUrl('www.google.com')))
```

this returns an earth icon not the icon of the site.

Comment: If you're on Windows, there is [no support for favicons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-module.html#notes).

Comment: Is there any way to get it

Comment: Probably. Try a third-party solution like [pyfav](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfav).

Comment: Ok, Thank you.I'll try it.

Comment: pyfav hadn't run with me is there any solution

Comment: You can search the web just as well as I can. Or fork [pyfav](https://github.com/phillipsm/pyfav/blob/master/pyfav/pyfav.py) and make your own library (it's only about 100 lines of code).